# Memberships adding price set without being selected

Tags: civimember, price-sets

I'm having some trouble regarding memberships at the moment. My organisation uses memberships to log and give access to a series of programme areas, and recently we've added a new programme area called Political Economy (POE) to the mix. To clarify, this is all using the backend. There is no public contribution page for these programme areas.

POE has a price set under organisation memberships, but this new one is now behaving oddly. We have a price set for 'all programme areas' and 'individual programme areas', and when using the indivdual programme areas and selecting specific programme areas that isn't POE, the membership gives acces to it regardless of whether it was selected. It shows it has no contribution, but the quantity being one. The image below of what it is showing now for all new 'individual programme areas' memberships:
[image]

And here is it with Public Economics (which was the programme area selected): [image]
I've tried re-arranging the order for the price set of POE, and selecting different programme areas under 'individual programme areas' but every time now it keeps giving access to POE.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please edit your question to indicate whether this is a public contribution page or someone adding a membership o the backend?  It also sounds like the problem is the access to POE.  Can you say more about how the access is granted?  Is it with CiviCRM Membership sync?

Comment: @JonG-MegaphoneTech I've edited the question to clairfy this is indeed using backend, as programme areas don't have a public contribution page. The Access is granted to programme areas via a domain/IP system. Members who have Public Economics membership, for example, would use either their institution IP or domain address to access the relevant programme area material, such as papers as so on. Upon further investigation, it appears this isn't isolated to POE, but other areas as well. When I add just POE, PE would come up as well. I'm relatively new to Civi, bear in mind